# How to render label with half transparent form using c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms.

- the first form is the background (The Black Opacity)
- the second form is the main form (This form uses TransparentKey)

I have this huge problem. I want to put some labels and other controls on top of the main form(second form), and when I put label or textbox with transparent background and run the application I get this ugly looking text:

(Without Text)
[image]

(With Text)
[image]

I search all over the internet with no success, and tried diffrent methods using OnPaint, but nothing seems to work.

[Some Info]

- The BackColor + TransparentKey is HotPink
- The Label ForeColor is Red
- The Label BackColor is Transparent / HotPink

If anyone have any directions or how to solve it, I will appreciate it!
(Sorry for my bad english..)

Comment: Don't use labels.  Just draw your text in the paint event of the container.

Comment: As i said. OnPaint is not working. I tried all methods.

Comment: Post your OnPaint code if you want help.

Comment: Your TransparencyKey selection is the problem, it is very bright.  So is the BackColor, the text rendering engine doesn't know any better than it should pick that bright color for the anti-aliasing pixels.  But the real background is black, now those anti-aliasing pixels have the wrong color and become very visible.  You'll have to pick a better value, make it very dark, if not Black.  It isn't otherwise obvious what the background window accomplishes.  If you are going to use it to show something else, like a bitmap, then you'll have this problem back.

Comment: Winforms does not directly support that... You could only have partial transparency at the form level... or write your own code. If you want such effect, better to use WPF instead. If you really want to use only Winforms, you might look at some third party component if tou don't want to write all the code yourself.

Comment: I Search for those custom labels & textboxes/ richtextboxes but couldn't fint anything..